# Panels - Style region to become a drop down/expandable menu

Tags: panels, theming, navigation

Please see: http://drupal.org/project/tableofcontents

I am using Panels and would like to style a panels region so I am able to hide/show just like the TOC module above.

I have looked on Drupal downloads for a module, but none work the way I want.

Any suggestions? Thanks for your time!

Answer (score 1):

I solved this by using the following module & some code:

http://drupal.org/project/panels_extra_styles

Panels region > Change style > Wrapper: raw.

**Content prefix:**

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="/misc/form.js"></script> 
<script type="text/javascript" src="/misc/collapse.js"></script> 
<form>
  <div>
    <fieldset class="collapsible form-wrapper">
      <legend>
        <span class="fieldset-legend">Attachments</span>
      </legend>
        <div class="fieldset-wrapper">
```

**Content suffix:**

```
        </div>
    </fieldset>
  </div>
</form>
```

Save and update. Voila!

References: Supplied if needed.

Answer (score 0):

Now there is a module for that:
https://www.drupal.org/project/panels_style_collapsible